# Max(case when) to expand indicator from single row to group of rows

Tags: postgresql, max, case-when

I need to expand the indicator (currently on daily basis) to a larger group (groups multiple consecutive days into one `grp`). I have following type of data:

```
id     date       grp   new_ind   traditional_ind
--------------------------------------------------
1    02-01-2021    1      1             0
1    02-02-2021    1      0             1
1    02-03-2021    1      0             0
1    02-04-2021    1     null          null 
1    02-06-2021    2      0             1
1    02-07-2021    2      0             0
2    02-01-2021    1     null          null
```

where `new_ind` and `traditional_ind` are mutually exclusive. With this, I am trying to create new indicator that expands the indicators that are currently on daily level to `grp` level, that will look like:

```
id     date       grp   new_ind   traditional_ind  final_type
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    02-01-2021    1      1             0            new       
1    02-02-2021    1      0             1            new
1    02-03-2021    1      0             0            new
1    02-04-2021    1     null          null          new
1    02-06-2021    2      0             1          traditional
1    02-07-2021    2      0             0          traditional
2    02-01-2021    1     null          null          none
```

basically,

1. if `new_ind` was ever 1, I want to flag entire `grp` as 'new'
2. if `new_ind=0` and if `traditional_ind` is ever 1, flag entire `grp` as 'traditional'
3. if both indicators were null, then flag entire `grp` as 'none'

so that each `id` and `grp` can have single value of `final_type`.

I've tried:

```
max(case when new_ind = 1 then 'New' 
    when traditional_ind = 1 then 'Traditional' 
    else 'None' end) over (partition by id, grp) as final_type
```

but this wouldn't recognize `when new_ind=1 then 'New'` and flag all of `new_ind = 1` as 'None' (but show traditional correctly):

```
id     date       grp   new_ind   traditional_ind  final_type
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    02-01-2021    1      1             0            none       
1    02-02-2021    1      0             1            none
1    02-03-2021    1      0             0            none
1    02-04-2021    1     null          null          none
1    02-06-2021    2      0             1          traditional
1    02-07-2021    2      0             0          traditional
2    02-01-2021    1     null          null          none
```

But if I remove else statement and only run:

```
max(case when new_ind = 1 then 'New' 
    when traditional_ind = 1 then 'Traditional' 
    end) over (partition by id, grp) as final_type
```

then this does accurately expand indicator as I hope, just returns null values (which I need to show as 'None' instead of nulls):

```
id     date       grp   new_ind   traditional_ind  final_type
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    02-01-2021    1      1             0            new       
1    02-02-2021    1      0             1            new
1    02-03-2021    1      0             0            new
1    02-04-2021    1     null          null          new
1    02-06-2021    2      0             1          traditional
1    02-07-2021    2      0             0          traditional
2    02-01-2021    1     null          null          null
```

Can anyone help identify issue with my max case when statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
WITH final_types AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    grp,
    ( case
      when bool_or(new_ind = 1) then 'New'
      when bool_or(traditional_ind = 1) then 'Traditional'
      else 'None'
      end
    ) AS final_type
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.final_type
FROM your_table t1
JOIN final_types t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.grp = t2.grp
```

Comment: @tlswpsl I'm actually curious: did this solve your issue?